# Populating UITableview using instance to fill array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, instance-variables

I've searched and haven't found anyone who has posted something such as this however if so, please feel free to point me in the right direction!

So using MVC, I've created an instance in my `UITableviewcontroller`

```
var brainLink = LessonBrain()
```

This is my viewDidLoad which should fetch data and populate the array 'subjectNameOneDay':

```
    let todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("subjectDictionary") ?? [:]

  brainLink.parseQuery(self.setupData.integerForKey("pupilNumber"), dictName: "subjectDictionary")

    self.subjectNameOneDay = todoDictionary["TwoTuesday"]! as! NSArray
```

`self.tableView.reloadData()`

The `brainLink` instance calls the method 'parseQuery':

```
func parseQuery(numberToRetreive: Int, dictName:String) {
        var tempArray:[String] = []


        if self.daysOfTheWeek.contains("\(self.currentDayOfTheWeekForLabel)") {

            print(currentDayOfTheWeekForLabel)


            print("parse query for data number \(numberToRetreive) started")

            let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: self.setupData.valueForKey("organisationID") as! String)
            query.fromLocalDatastore()
            query.whereKey("PupilNumber", equalTo: "\(numberToRetreive)")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

                if (error == nil) {

                    print("Successfully retrieved 2 \(objects)")

                    for object in objects! {

                        var periodCounter = 1

                        while periodCounter <= 6 {

                            print(self.currentDayOfTheWeekForData)


                            tempArray.append(object.valueForKey("\(self.currentDayOfTheWeekForData)P\(periodCounter)") as! String)
                            print(tempArray)

                            periodCounter += 1

                        }

                        self.addItem(tempArray, weekDayPeriod: self.currentDayOfTheWeekForData, dictionaryName: dictName)

                    }
                }else {
                    print(error!.userInfo)
                }
            }
        }else{
            print("It's the weekend!")
        }
        print("query function returning temp array")

    }
```

This all works fine and populates the array however the issue I am having is that no matter what I have tried or where I place my `self.tableView.reloadData()` It does not ever 'wait' for the data to be fetched before trying to reload the table.

Where can I put this code/arrange it so it fetches data THEN reloads?

Comment: add the reloadData  to your callback, not the view did load.  By this point the new data will have been retrieved.

Comment: apologies for my ignorance.....how would I add it to my callback? do you mean return self.tableView.reloadData()  from the parseQuery function??

Comment: yes, but you need a address by reference so _weak MyTableViewClass *MyClass = self. Then in parse query function mylass.reloadData (you should check my class hasn't been nil'd out before calling it's method). you need to make sure that the tableview datasource is also populated before the my class.reloadData is called.

Answer (score 0):

The above line:

`query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in`

starts a completion handler.  This block will run whenever the call completes, so the thread of execution will continue over this, which is why when your `reloadData` call runs, it hasn't added the objects to your array yet.

If you put your `reloadData` call as the last thing that happens in this block, you'll be closer to getting the results you want.

You should also ensure that you're running on the main thread when you make UI calls though.  Since your completion block could execute on any thread, you could do this:

```
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew.......putting the reload in he last line of the block gives me an error.....the method is in another class which is not a UITableViewController subclass so cannot load. Where would the above code be placed?

Comment: You could replace the reload call above with a function call to your class where you could call reload on your table.